# Creating Maven Archetype: is there a way to specify a default groupId

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-archetype

I have created a maven archetype using `create-from-project`. Is there a way to specify a default `groupId`?

This archetype is for internal use only, default `groupId` would save some keystrokes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by specifying a [`propertyFile`](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-from-project-mojo.html#propertyFile)

This property file may contains few properties including default groupId. So something like this (in a file named something.properties):

```
groupId=com.company
```

and to create the archetype

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project -Darchetype.properties=../something.properties
```

another example [here](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/create-with-property-file.html)

Comment: Doesn't work for me - when I use mvn archetype:generate from archetype catalog, it still asks me for groupId and nothing is default

Comment: @Destil Did you create the archetype yourself ?

Comment: @Destil did you prefix your groupId property with `archetype.` ? i.e. `archetype.groupId=com.company`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a "default" groupId because of company conventions, you can define it directly in the pom.xml in the archetype-resources directory (just replace the ${groupId} with your desired value. So it doesn't matter what the user of the archetype specifies.